# Don't hyperlink whole content of "copied content" if it starts with http

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-proposals

When you include some text information in the "copied content" field in the Documentation review, it doesn't get hyperlinked. So far so good.

But if you start the content with a link, everything will get hyperlinked, including text. For example in [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/146233), I included 2 hyperlinks separated with an "and" and some unecessary text at the end that I shouldn't have.

But the whole content becomes a hyperlink, which is wrong:

> https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html%20and%20https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-compiler-api.html%20and%20probably%20more,%20I%20stopped%20looking%20after%20those%202...